# Python, How to catch an additional argument from command line

Tags: python, terminal, arguments

What's the best way to check for additional arguments from command line in Python? i.e. if the normal execution line is `/Python-3.6.2/bin/python myScript.py`
is there a syntax to catch `/Python-3.6.2/bin/python myScript.py /documents/file.txt`? So far I have been try,except for IndexError.

```
try:
   f = sys.argv[1]
   ...
except IndexError:
   ...
```

Whats a better way if any?

Comment: Best practice to work with arguments is to use [ArgumentParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Just check the length of it. If you're thinking there could be more than one, get the length of sys.argv, with len(sys.argv). Check it to see it its greater or equal to one.

Comment: What's the problem in `sys.argv[2]` ?

Comment: @HunterBerry checking the length is a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at **0**, position **0** is reserved for the script name so arguments start on **1**

```
import sys
try:
   f = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
   pass
```